# Query on varchar vs foreign key performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for SQL Server.

I have a table that will contain a lot of rows and that table will be queried multiple times so I need to make sure my design is optimized.

Just for the question let say that table contains 2 columns. Name and Type.
Name is a varchar and it will be unique.

Type can be 5 different value (type1... type5). (It possible can contains more values in the future)

Should I make type a varchar (and create an index) or would be it better to create a table of types that will contains 5 rows with only a column for the name and make type a foreign key?

Is there a performance difference between both approach? The queries will not always have the same condition. Sometime it will query the name, type, or both with different values.

EDIT: Consider that in my application if type would be a table, the IDs would be cached so I wouldn't have to query the Type table everytime.

Comment: Performance wise, if there are any, it should be negligible. The main question should be which is a better design. And what is your requirement. For 1st method, there isn't any itegrity and you may inser 'type1' or 'type    1' with space inbetween, and it will treated as different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you'll probably get better query performance if you keep all the data in one table. However doing this is known as "denormalization" and comes with a number of pretty significant drawbacks.

1. If your table has "a lot of rows", storing an extra `varchar` field for every row as opposed to say, a small, or even tinyint, can add a non-trivial amount of size to your table
2. If any of that data needs to change, you'll have to perform lots of updates against that table. This means transaction log growth and potential blocking on the table during modification locks. If you store it as a separate table with 5-ish rows, if you need to update the data associated with that data, you just update one of the 5 rows you need.
3. Denormalizing data means that the definition of that data is no longer stored in one place, but in multiple places (actually its stored across every single row that contains those values).
4. For all the reasons listed above, managing that data (inserts, updates, deletes, and simply *defining* the data) can quickly become far more overhead than simply normalizing the data correctly in the first place, and for little to no benefit beyond what can be done with proper indexing.

If you find the need to return both the "big" table and some other information from the `type` table and you're worried about join performance, truthfully, wouldn't be. That's a generalization, but If your big table has, say, 500M rows in it, I can't see many use cases where you'd want all those rows returned; you're probably going to get a subset. In which case, that join might be more manageable. Provided you index `type`, the join should be pretty snappy.

If you do go the route of denormalizing your data, I'd recommend still having the lookup table as the "master definition" of what a "type" is, so it's not a conglomeration of millions of rows of data.

If you STILL want to denormalize the data WITHOUT a lookup table, at least put a `CHECK` constraint on the column to limit which values are allowable or not.

Comment: I will most likely normalize the data. This is an application that will be importing data from another system. The data from the other system is denormalized and I was wondering if normalizing it would allow me to gain performance with lots of rows.

I'm not worried about the JOIN  performance cost because I might not have to do one. It is strictly when doing a WHERE on that column using an ID that is cached in the application.

Answer (score 0):

How much is "a lot of rows"?. 
If it is hundreds of thousands or more, then a [Columnstore Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589807(v=sql.120).aspx) may be a good fit.

It depends on your needs, but usually you would want the type column to be of a numerical value (in your case tinyint).